# Automatic table to create a list of specific inputs

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to create a Google spreadsheet, with the start of the table a pop up window comes with a question of whether it is an Entry or Pickup.

After the decision, it should fulfill certain tasks after the election.

When choosing an Entry, a form should appear where you have to provide certain information. (The entered information should also be automatically inserted on the Google Table by the script.)

When selecting a Pickup, another form will appear that compares the information entered with the list of Google Sheets.

And upon successful approval, it should fullfill on the list in the Pickup section.

My question is whether it is possible with Google Drive to create such a script.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is whether it is possible with Google Drive to create such a script.

Yes.

You can create such a script with Google Sheets with [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) by using [UI Modals](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui.html#showmodaldialoguserinterface,-title). Create a HTML Form on these modals and when the submit button is pressed send the data to a custom function that places the data on your sheet.

You can have this executed when the file is opened thanks to [Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers).